# Tunneling PPTP VPN and network setup for bridged KVM running Windows 7 enterprise on Linux host

Tags: networking, vpn, pptp

I'm using a Win7 provided image from work to run inside qemu-kvm (libvirt/virt-manager). The host is running Debian Wheezy.

The Win7 VM wants to join the company AD and has certain tools to check if I'm on the corporate network. I configured the network interfaces to have a bridge br0 connected to eth0.

When I'm in office the virtual machine is directly on the corporate network and gets an IP using DHCP.

When I'm at home, the virtual machine gets a 192.168.1.X IP adress from my home router.

On the host machine I can start a PPTP VPN tunnel to the corporate network which is connected to ppp0 interface.

My question is, can I use the ppp0 tunnel in the virtual machine? Adding ppp0 to bridge br0 does not work.

Comment: Why create the VPN from the host?  Why not just initiate the VPN from within Windows?

Comment: Because I also work on the host, and for those things that can't be done under Linux I want to use the guest. Seems feels silly to setup two tunnels, one from the host, the other from the guest. But that is what I'm doing at the moment. Looking for a better solution.